# jQuery : use .next() to select next selector

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML code :

```
  <div id="slides">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" class="current">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="">7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
$('#slides li a.current').next('li a').addClass("current");
```

but that's not work, where is my mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/636vV/

Comment: Hiya, Hmm you want current to change on click? cheerios!

Comment: @NuLLeR saweet man made a small demo for you, see below, cheerios!

Comment: @Tats_innit where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#slides a.current').parent('li').next("li").find("a").addClass("current");
```

Comment: you could make it as Accepted if it suited your need

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#slides a.current').parent('li').next('li').find('a').addClass("current");
```

**OR**

```
$('#slides a.current').parent('li').next('li').children('a').addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#slides li a.current').parent().next().find('a').addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slides li a.current').parent().next().find('a').addClass("current");​​​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/636vV/15/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slides li:has(a[class="current"])').next().find('a').addClass("current")
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/636vV/23/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go demo = http://jsfiddle.net/ncdjU/1/

Hope this helps and have a nice one!

**Jquery code**

```
   $('#slides > ul > li').click(function() {

    $('#slides > ul > li > a.current').removeClass('current');

    $(this).find('a').addClass("current");

});​
```